# I am trying to solve 12503 problem in UVA online judge. I think their is a problem while using string::back()

Tags: c++, arrays, string

The problem is simple. But I tried to submit two different codes, one of them got a WA verdict while the other one got a AC verdict. The solutions are nearly same. Just by changing the input mechanism the solution gets accepted. I can't understand what the problem is. Link to the problem is [here](https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=608&page=show_problem&problem=3947).

**Abridged Problem Statement:**

You have a robot standing on the origin of x axis. The robot will be given some instructions. Your
task is to predict its position after executing all the instructions.

- LEFT: move one unit left (decrease p by 1, where p is the position
  of the robot before moving)
- RIGHT: move one unit right (increase p
  by 1)
- SAME AS i: perform the same action as in the i-th
  instruction. It is guaranteed that i is a positive integer not
  greater than the number of instructions before this

**Input**:
The first line contains the number of test cases T (T ≤ 100). Each test case begins with an integer n
(1 ≤ n ≤ 100), the number of instructions. Each of the following n lines contains an instruction.

**Output**
For each test case, print the final position of the robot.

**Note** that after processing each test case, the
robot should be reset to the origin.

**Sample Input**

```
2
3
LEFT
RIGHT
SAME AS 2
5
LEFT
SAME AS 1
SAME AS 2
SAME AS 1
SAME AS 4
```

**Sample Output**

```
1
-5
```

Here's the code which got AC verdict:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int TC = 0 , N = 0 , p = 0 , in = 0;
string instruction , as;
vector<string> instructions;

int main() {
    cin >> TC;
    while(TC--) {
    cin >> N; p = 0; scanf("\n");
    instructions.assign(N , "");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; ++i) {
        cin >> instruction;
        if(instruction.compare("LEFT") == 0) {
        instructions[i] = instruction;
        }
        else if(instruction.compare("RIGHT") == 0) {
        instructions[i] = instruction;
        }
        else { scanf("\n");
        cin >> as >> in;
        instructions[i] = instructions[in - 1];
        }
    }
    for(auto x : instructions) {
        if(x.compare("RIGHT") == 0) ++p;
        else --p;
    }
    cout << p << endl;
    instructions.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here, is the code which got WA verdict:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int TC = 0 , N = 0 , p = 0 , in = 0;
string instruction , as;
vector<string> instructions;

int main() {
    cin >> TC;
    while(TC--) {
    cin >> N; p = 0; scanf("\n");
    instructions.assign(N , "");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; ++i) {
        getline(cin , instruction);
        if(instruction.compare("LEFT") == 0) {
        instructions[i] = instruction;
        }
        else if(instruction.compare("RIGHT") == 0) {
        instructions[i] = instruction;
        }
        else { 
        instructions[i] = instructions[instruction.back() - '0' - 1]; // I think the problem is here but don't know what it is. 
        }
    }
    for(auto x : instructions) {
        if(x.compare("RIGHT") == 0) ++p;
        else --p;
    }
    cout << p << endl;
    instructions.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe instruction.back() is creating some problem. Please clarify my doubt.

Comment: [Please read this about that bits.h header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Most likely [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction) because of `getline`.

Comment: Links can break. Its better if you include the problem statement in the question itself